# How can I change the print color in Python?

Tags: python

I want to use the normal `print()` statement of python but with a given color (e.g. green)

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: You can look at this thread for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I also wrote a comment, but for those of you who overlooked that:

There actually already are many questions raised regarding this topic on Stackoverflow.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) post for example to get a good overview on how to print in color to the terminal.

I hope I could help :)

Comment: thank you!! i marked the question as already answered